# Combine/merge data from separate elastic search indexes based on @timestamp

Tags: python, elasticsearch, nosql, denormalization

I have three separate indexes in elasticsearch, each storing data every second. I would like to combine data from all three indexes at @timestamp T, and return a single document.

How do I achieve this? Is there a query I can write?

I have been reading about denormalization. Do I have to write a script, in something like Python, and create a new document in a new index with the combined data for every unique @timestamp? If so, how does this script get executed to ensure the index is always up to date? manually? cron? triggered by elasticsearch when a conditions is met?

I am new to elasticsearch so any help and sample code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so are you merging all three indexes to new one or any one out of three ?

Comment: I'm not sure what best practice is here, but I would say to create a new one.

Comment: _forcemerge and reindex both API will help you to merge all this index